# How can i make the computer player in my game stop after it has earned 20 points in one turn?

Tags: java

I have been trying to make a game in java called pig where a player rolls 2 dice. the player earns point based off of what they roll for example if the player rolls 5 and 4 he now has 9 points but if the player rolls a 1 they gain no points and control switches over to the computer and if the player rolls snake eyes ( 1 and 1) the player loses all point and control switches over to the computer. i have the game working but i need to stop the computer after it gains 20 points in its turn. Whichever player hits 100 first wins.

**Here is my code:**

```
//this program runs 4.4
import java.util.Scanner;


public class run {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        dice thing = new dice();
        dice thing1 = new dice();
        boolean control=true;
        int x = 0,points=0,a,b,y=0,c,d,turn=0,save=0,no=0;
        while(x<100 && y<100)
        {
            while (control == true && x<100)
                {       
                    a=thing.roll();
                    b=thing1.roll();
                    if (a == 1 && b==1)
                    {
                        control=false;
                        System.out.println("your first die rolled a " + thing.getroll() + " second die rolled a " + thing1.getroll()+"computer now has control");
                        x=0;
                    }
                    else if(a == 1 || b==1)
                    {
                        control = false;
                        System.out.println("your first die rolled a " + thing.getroll() + " second die rolled a " + thing1.getroll() + " now you have " + x +" points "+"computer now has control");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    x +=(a+b);
                    System.out.println("your first die rolled a " + thing.getroll() + " your second die rolled a  " + thing1.getroll() + " now you have " + x +" points" );
                System.out.println(" would you like to end your turn put in  1 for yes 0 for no");
                    points = scan.nextInt();
                    if(points==1)
                    {
                        control= false;
                    }
                    if (x>=100)
                        {
                            System.out.println("you win");
                        }
                    }
            }

            while (control==false && y<100)
                {   
                    c=thing.roll();
                    d=thing1.roll();

                    if (c == 1 && d==1)
                        {
                            control=true;
                            System.out.println("The computers first die rolled a " + thing.getroll() + " The computers second die rolled a " + thing1.getroll()+"you now have control");
                            turn = y;
                            y=0;
                        }
                    else if(c == 1 || d==1)
                        {
                            control = true;
                            System.out.println("The computers first die rolled a " + thing.getroll() + " The computers second die rolled a " + thing1.getroll()+ " now the computer has  " + y +" points "+"you now have control");
                            turn = y;
                        }
                    else
                        {
                        y +=(c+d);
                    System.out.println("The computers first die rolled a  " + thing.getroll() + " The computers second die rolled a " + thing1.getroll() + " now the computer has  " + y +" points" );
                        turn = y;
                        if (y>=100)
                            {
                                System.out.println("you lose");
                            }
                        }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how could you gain 20 points in a turn? At best you could gain 12 (6+6)? Or are we dealing with dice that have more than 6 sides?

Comment: @MarcB In real-life [pig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_%28dice_game%29), at least, your turn doesn't end after just one roll. Your turn ends when you roll a 1 (you loose the points for this turn) or when you choose to hold (you keep the points for this turn). I haven't looked through the code to see if the same is true here.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
if (turn >= 20){
    control = true;
    turn = 0;
}
```

after:

```
while (control==false && y<100)
            {
```